# When parsing week of the year in lubridate I always get the same date

Tags: r

I try to turn a string with the format WeekYear into a date using parse_date_time from lubridate. But I always get the same date in return.

```
library(lubridate)
> isoweek(parse_date_time("092015", orders = "WY"))
[1] 53
```

Shouldn't it work like:?

```
> month(parse_date_time("092015", orders = "mY"))
[1] 9
```

It doesn't get better when I add the first day of the week to the calender weeks:

```
> test <- c("2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2014-12-12")
> parse_date_time(paste(isoyear(test),isoweek(test),"1", sep = "-"), "YWw")
[1] "2013-01-07 UTC" "2013-02-04 UTC" "2014-12-15 UTC"
```

The first date should be "2012-12-31" (the monday of the first week 2013).
The second date should be "2013-01-28" and 
the third should be "2014-12-08".

This gave me the idea for the following:

```
> parse_date_time(paste(isoyear(test),isoweek(test),"1", sep = "-"), "YWw") - weeks(1)
[1] "2012-12-31 UTC" "2013-01-28 UTC" "2014-12-08 UTC"
```

which works but produces errors (NA) for dates at the end of 2015 (week 53).

More precisely, the errors emerge from 2015-12-28 to 2016-01-03:

```
> test <- c("2015-12-27","2015-12-28","2015-12-31","2016-01-01","2016-01-03","2016-01-04")
> parse_date_time(paste(isoyear(test),isoweek(test),"1", sep = "-"), "YWw") - weeks(1)
[1] "2015-12-21 UTC" NA               NA               NA               NA               "2015-12-28 UTC"
```

I found a solution with the package "ISOweek":

```
> library(ISOweek)
> test <- c("2015-12-27","2015-12-28","2015-12-31","2016-01-01","2016-01-03","2016-01-04")
> ISOweek2date(paste(ISOweek(test),"1", sep = "-"))
[1] "2015-12-21" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-28" "2016-01-04"
```

Comment: I also couldn't get the week of the year to parse - tried the alternate formatting flag `U` with the same result. If you drop the `isoweek()` call, you will see that `parse_date_time()` is consistently returning `2015-12-28`, regardless of which week you put at the start of the string. It might be worth reporting this on the Github repo for lubridate.

Comment: It looks like you have hit a bug where there is no day specified, so it gets todays date, and replaces the week with that. You can fix it by giving lubridate a day to work with: `parse_date_time("1092015", orders = "%u%W%Y", exact = T)`

Comment: You must be very careful when working with week of the year and the numbering of days in a week. There are at least three different conventions: US, UK, ISO8601. They differ in the definition of the first day of the week, the first of the year, the number of weeks in a year, and other subtleties.